# Right way to get parameters in an entity

Tags: symfony, jmsserializerbundle

I want to access to the complete url of my photo in one of my entity.

The entity (PlacePhoto) is serialised with the JMSSerializerBundle when I consume my API.

Here a sample of my entity:

```
/**
 * @VirtualProperty
 */
public function getUrl()
{
    return 'https://xxxx.s3.amazonaws.com/' . $this->path;
}
```

The CDN path (https://xxxx.s3.amazonaws.com/) is in my parameters.yml file, and I would prefer to access to that value instead of writing directly the path in my entity.

What is the right way to do it? I know that I can access to the parameters by creating a service, but I don't see how and when I could call it in my code, knowing that I access to the photos through my Place entity (one-to-many relationship) that way:

```
public function getPlaceAction()
{
    $places = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('CyrAppBundle:Place')->findAll()

    return $places;
}
```

Is there a way to do it ? maybe during the serialisation?

**EDIT 27/08/2015**

I managed to do it by creating a [doctrine listener](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html) on the `postLoad` event.

My services.yml

```
services:
   app.listener.placephoto_helper:
       class: Cyr\AppBundle\Listener\PlacePhotoHelper
       arguments: [%cdn_webpath%]
       tags:
           - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postLoad, connection: default }
```

My listener

```
<?php

namespace Cyr\AppBundle\Listener;

use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Cyr\AppBundle\Entity\PlacePhoto;

class PlacePhotoHelper
{
   private $cdnWebPath;

    public function __construct($cdnWebPath)
    {
        $this->cdnWebPath = $cdnWebPath;
    }

    public function postLoad(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();
        $entityManager = $args->getEntityManager();

        if ($entity instanceof PlacePhoto) {
           $entity->setUrl($this->cdnWebPath . '/' . $entity->getPath());
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Great solution!

Comment: Since symfony 4 you can use $_ENV['parameter_name'] wherever needed in your application

Comment: @SBO was that removed in Symfony 5? I tried dumping $_ENV and don't see the parameters anywhere

Comment: no, you can check it here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html#configuration-based-on-environment-variables

Answer (score -1):

I would prefer to add a new service: ImageHelper. Give this helper a a GetUrl() method that accepts one mandatory parameter: your Entity.

e.g.

```
class ImageHelper
{
    private $container;

    public function __construct(Container $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function getUrl(Image $image)
    {
        $base_url = $this->container->getParameter('image.base_url');
        return $base_url . $image->getPath();
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: You don't need to inject the whole container in the service (this is a very bad pratice) if you need to inject only one configuration parameter (you can inject only what you really need).

Comment: This doesn't solve the use inside an entity. Because if you need the ImageHelper using the container (or parameter coming from the constructor) you cannot use static methods. So, you need to create a new ImageHelper() inside your Entity's method, but the helper now need the container in the constructor, so you need to use new ImageHelper($container) in your entity, and the container is not available, so you're back to the beginning.